# Use logon group policy to add a new registry key failed

Tags: windows, group-policy

I setup a group policy logon script to add a new registry key. It adds a new registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\GDSRI123]
"AutoTranslate"="No"

The way I do this is to create two files. One is the file that contains the registry key setting 
(settings.reg). The other file is a batch file(logon.bat) which executes settings.reg file.

The file doesnt get executed by group policy/logon policy. However, The batch file executes perfectly when I double click the Logon.bat file in the Logon Folder:
\abc.com\SysVol\abc.com\Policies{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}\User\Scripts\Logon

Any idea why logon group policy doesn't work?

Comment: No, but you'd be a lot better off just creating the registry key directly via Group Policy rather than running a batch file.  (Preferences: Windows Settings: Registry.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston How do I create the registry key directly via GP?

Comment: Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Windows Settings -> Registry.